# I do not get to validate the size of the image with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I am trying validate the size of the image with this method found in:

https://gist.github.com/1862084

but the validate is skiped and big images are uploaded :( without problem.

I have write my model and my uploader in this comment:

https://gist.github.com/1009861#gistcomment-80738

I paste the code here:

My model:

```
require 'file_size_validator'
 class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  mount_uploader :posted, PostedUploader, mount_on: :posted_filename
  field :posted
  field :posted_cache
  field :remove_posted
  field :remote_posted_url
  validates :posted, :presence => true, :file_size => { :maximum => 0.5.megabytes.to_i  } 
end
```

In my posted_uploader.rb

```
 require 'carrierwave/processing/mini_magick'
 class PostedUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
 storage :grid_fs

 def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end

process :resize_to_limit => [560, 560]
process :convert => :png

#versions
  version :medium do
    process :resize_to_fit => [200,380]
    process :convert => :png
  end

  version :big do
    process :resize_to_limit => [560, 560]
    process :convert => :png
  end

 version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [61, 61]
    process :convert => :png
  end 

  version :superthumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]
    process :convert => :png
  end 

   def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

   def filename
    if not super.nil?
    super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '.png'
    end
   end

end
```

**I'm using mongoid**

Where have I the problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: The problem was fixed. I have removed this line for that the file size validator works fine:  `process :resize_to_limit => [560, 560]`